# JAVA Midi: Using percussion sound on two channels, channel 10 and another

Tags: java, midi, channel

I'd like to be able to play percussion sounds on two channels, so that I can sent one channel to the left (pan 0) and one to the right (pan 127) to have a stereo effect.

I want to play two percussions sounds concurrently, one on the left, one on the right.

Here is some code:

```
final Synthesizer synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
synthesizer.open();
channel = synthesizer.getChannels()[9];
...
channel.controlChange (10,0); // pan left
channel.noteOn (35, 64);
channel.controlChange (10,127); // pan right
channel.noteOn (36, 64);
```

This code doesn't work, since as soon as the pan right is executed, the note that is meant to sound on the left sounds on the right. It works OK if two channels are used, but so far I haven't been able to work out how to get the percussion sound on the second channel.

Can the instrument from channel 10 be copied to another channel? I don't have much hope, since this post says "not possible":

[channel 10 (percussion) with output in stereo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964318/midioutshortmsg-on-channel-10-percussion-with-output-in-stereo)

Comment: What synthesizer are you using?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. I'm using the synthesizer that comes with Java, playback through the audio system of the PC. No external hardware involved.

Comment: Hi, same problem here, did you find the solution? Thanks.

Comment: There is no solution. Percussion is bound to one channel only. I ended up using two different channels, one can go to the left, the other one to the right. Sadly I can't have percussion on both channels, but the normal channels also offer some percussion sounds, like wood block, agogo, tom-tom. Try the result here: [link](http://www.jorgk.com/music/)